# JQuery checkbox with options framework and wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

This is a jquery question, and since I am working with WordPress and options framework in the admin panel, I have to hide certain options with a checkbox. The problem is one of the elements is a dropdown menu and it seems that I cannot hide it at the beginning (meaning if I click twice the dropdown disappears as it should) although the code works for the text input. Here is the code:

```
jQuery('#telephone_hidden').click(function() {

    if (jQuery('#telephone_hidden').attr('checked') ? true : false) {
        jQuery('#section-telephone_dropdown_icons, #section-telephone_number_hidden').show();
    } else {
        jQuery('#section-telephone_dropdown_icons, #section-telephone_number_hidden').fadeToggle(400);
    }
});
```

I am not very good with jQuery but I think that this should work, or at least there is a better way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `if` statement with a ternary statement ... not going to work. Try this:

```
if (jQuery('#telephone_hidden').prop('checked')){
    jQuery('#section-telephone_dropdown_icons, #section-telephone_number_hidden').show();
} else {
    jQuery('#section-telephone_dropdown_icons, #section-telephone_number_hidden').fadeToggle(400);
}
```

The `.prop('checked')` returns a boolean, which I think is what you want to validate. Also, there really isn't a need to use `jQuery` if you properly set up your libraries to not conflict. You can consolidate it to:

```
if ($('#telephone_hidden').prop('checked')){
    $('#section-telephone_dropdown_icons, #section-telephone_number_hidden').show();
} else {
    $('#section-telephone_dropdown_icons, #section-telephone_number_hidden').fadeToggle(400);
}
```

This doesn't seem like much, but over an entire script file you reduce its size and therefore improve its performance. Depending on how big your file is, it can have a huge impact.

Also, noticed you were using the `.click` event for `$('#telephone_hidden')`, so rather than query the DOM again, try this:

```
var $tel = $('#section-telephone_dropdown_icons, #section-telephone_number_hidden');

$('#telephone_hidden').on('click',function() {
    if ($(this).prop('checked')){
        $tel.show();
    } else {
        $tel.fadeToggle(400);
    }
});
```

The use of `$(this)` prevents needing to query the DOM for the selector again, and I cache the selector used for the `show` / `fadeToggle`, providing another performance boost.

I know this is a long answer, but I figured if I showed the step-by-step process of improvement you could learn and apply it to future jQuery endeavors.

Comment: All of the above work fine and i already tried with prop and that also seems to work. However the dropdown menu stays the same. It seems it might be options framework problem rather than jquery. Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Try [.is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/)

```
if (jQuery('#telephone_hidden').is(':checked')) {
```

or [.prop](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

```
if (jQuery('#telephone_hidden').prop('checked')){
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`is`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) function in conjunction with the [`checked`](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) selector, like so:

```
if ($('#telephone_hidden').is(':checked')) {
   // ... do something
}
```